# How do I calculate where a solid fuel rocket will land if the rocket is launched at a 45 degree angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, rocket-science

Let's say I was launching a model rocket at a 45 degree angle to find the distance between the rocket's landing site and the rocket's launching site, but before launch I wanted to try and calculate where the rocket would land. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi. Clearly. You seem unaware just how complex such a calculation would be, more so because you provide very little detail.

Comment: You should take it as a point particle to maintain the simplicity after that calculate it's maximum parabolic trajectory ( as it's 45°) through formula ( I assume the launching and landing both took place on earth). If not, then you should modify your question.

Comment: @Gert you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Gert Sorry. I'm not very good at math and I haven't been taught about mathematical physics yet. What I mean is "How would I calculate the distance (in meters) from the point where a model rocket lands to the point from which it is launched, if the rocket were to be launched at a 45 degree vertical angle?" This probably doesn't clarify more but I hope it does.

Comment: Although remember my answer has lots of fallacies ( if not what I assumed) but it's according to your question.

Comment: @ShaneMcDonald This still isn't straightforward.  For one thing, we would at least need to know how the fuel burns and how much fuel it has, and how much it weighs with and without the fuel.  To get an accurate picture you would also need to account for air resistance, and wind conditions, possibly even effects due to Earth's rotation.  Equations for rockets are pretty complicated.  It's hard to get an accurate number without factoring in a lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall, the model rockets my son use to build used a separate fuel and nozzle pack.  They burned out very quickly. If you know the speed after burnout, a simple range equation will give an estimate of the distance. To calculate the speed, you will need the masses of the rocket and the fuel pack, and the thrust or impulse from the pack. (You might check the web-site of the manufacturer.) Or, find an open space, fire the thing, and see how far it goes. Then you can calculate back to the initial speed.

Comment: What equation would I use to find the range that uses the speed after burnout?

Comment: The formula for the range of an non-powered projectile leaving from the ground and not affected by friction is R = $v_o^2$ sin(2θ)/g where $v_o$ is the initial velocity in m/sec and g = 9.8 m/s/s.  If  θ = 45 degrees then sin(2θ) =1.

Comment: Is the range in meters?

Comment: Note that units of measure carry through calculations just like numbers.  In this case $(m/sec)^2$/(m/$sec^2$) = m. Being aware of this, provides one method of locating errors in your calculations.

Comment: So it is meters, gotcha. Thanks for helping me!