# What equation should I use if I am estimating the distance of a rocket's landing point to the point it was launched from?

Tags: mathematical-physics, projectile

I am trying to figure out how to estimate how far (in meters) that a solid fuel model rocket will land from its launching point. To do this, I have figured out I will need to estimate the maximum altitude that the rocket will reach, and the time of the flight from the maximum altitude all the way to the impact point. How can I do this?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589716/how-do-i-calculate-where-a-solid-fuel-rocket-will-land-if-the-rocket-is-launched

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neglecting air drag, a projectile launched from the origin with speed $v_0$ at angle $\theta$ from the horizontal has a simple parabolic trajectory given by

$$x(t)=(v_0\cos\theta)t$$

$$z(t)=(v_0\sin\theta)t-\frac12gt^2$$

where $g$ is the acceleration of gravity. Here $x$ is the horizontal coordinate, $z$ is the vertical one, and $t$ is the time since launch.

These two equations tell you everything about the flight. For example, you can find the flight time by setting $z$ to zero. Putting that into the first equation then gives the horizontal range. The maximum altitude is the value of $z$ halfway through the flight. With some calculus you can do more complicated things like determining the angle that maximizes the range.

If your rocket has a significant thrust duration, the trajectory is considerably more complicated because you have a second force acting for part of the flight, and acting in a varying direction.

If you want to take air drag into account, the trajectory is also considerably more complicated. This is a third force, acting throughout the flight, and in a varying direction.

So I advise using these simple equations to begin with, and seeing if they suffice.

Comment: What would the equation for finding the horizontal range look like? I'm not very good at math like this since i'm at the beginning of being taught pre-algebra.

Comment: @ShaneMcDonald A comment on an answer to your previous question had that formula: $R = v_0^2\sin{(2\theta)}/g$.

Comment: Would R be measured in meters?

Comment: If $v_0$ is in m/s and $g$ in m/s$^2$ then you can see that it will be.